# Reformatting a date in excel, remove square brackets and time stamp

Tags: excel

I have a many dates in this format [19/09/1983 00:00:00] is there a way to change it to 19/09/1983.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With data in **A1**, in another cell enter:

```
=MID(A1,2,10)
```

[image]